# Failed to retrieve server version error in Visual Studio 2019 data connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, ssas, data-analysis, ssas-tabular

While opening tables from server explorer data connection its showing the error:

> failed to retrieve server version

and tables are not opening

All compatibility are ok. How to solve this please help?

Comment: Which sql server version are you using? Sounds like there's a mismatch

Comment: I'm using sql server 2022

Comment: I don't think VS 2019 supports that version

Comment: so shall i upgrade the version of visual studio to 2022

Comment: Yes. its solved after upgrading Visual Studio to 2022. Thank you